# How to submit user score in Flurry SDK (Android and iOS)

Tags: google-analytics, flurry

So, my need is I submit user score to Flurry, in order to gain information about how much the average score that user can achieve. 
I have setup logEventWithParameter

- Event Name = "Game Result"
- Parameters = {"USER_SCORE",""}

And then I look into my flurry dashboard, it doesn't count the average value of USER_SCORE parameter. I think I have mistaken about how Flurry work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer! at the [Flurry`s FAQ](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ/Events) written:

> **Are there limits to the number of Events and Parameters I can create?** Yes, there is a limit of 300 Events for each application.
>   Each event can have up to 10 parameters, and each parameter can have
>   any number of values.
>
> Note that we currently display only the top 500 parameter values for
>   any Event in the Flurry portal. If you want to track something like a
>   score, which can have an infinite number of values, we would recommend
>   creating a distribution for your parameter values.

Unfortunately, Flurry doesn't support this kind of use case. So I have to create score distribution group, something like SCORE_GROUP = {0-5000, 5001-10000, >10000}